# similar values in hashmap and arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

My program is running normally but it is giving false results. I use a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` and an `ArrayList<Integer>` and my program generates a new `HashMap<integer, ArrayList<Integer>>`. The program must compare each value in the `HashMap` with the value in the `ArrayList` and add similar values and store the results in the new `HashMap`. I've added a picture to help you understand.

[image: algorithm]

Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> : 
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Hashmap<Integer,ArrayList<integer>> :
  1, [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
  2, [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
  3, [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Result:

```
HashMap
  1, 4
  2, 3
  3, 2
```

Code:

```
System.out.println("HASHMAP SIMILIRATE RESULT:");
HashMap<Integer, Integer> sim = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

int count;
int k = 1;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
    count = 0;

    //you can move this part to another method to avoid deep nested code
    for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {
        if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k))) {
            count = count + 1;        
        }
    }

    sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @StinePike   
I posted it sorry

Comment: I tried helping OP earlier today but the code is too messy and his problem just doesn't make sense.

Comment: there should be compiler error

Comment: @Jacob 
I add an image to help you understand

Comment: @StinePike 
It gives me false results

Comment: @StinePike There's a lot more code that isn't shown and it's very messy.

Comment: @fatoma Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: are the sizes of both arraylist are same?

Comment: @StinePike  yes it's same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int k = 0; // initiate k with 0
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
    count = 0;

    //you can move this part to another method to avoid deep nested code
    for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {
        if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k++))) {
            count = count + 1;        
        }
    }

    sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
    k=0;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :). if you find it helpful then you can upvote the answer and accept it to close this

Comment: And most importantly I hope that you have understood where was your fault in code